# django-microsoft-auth : The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid

Tags: python-3.x, azure, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, django-3.1

I am creating a Single Sign-On(SSO) with the help of Azure AD and Django. I am using

> Python==3.8

> Django==3.1

> django-microsoft-auth==2.4.0

I followed the tutorial on https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

but I am getting this error when I try to login with the register email id after completing the 10 steps. The redirect URI in the azure ad that I use is https://localhost:8080/microsoft/auth-callback/
[image]

Comment: How did you managed to go to the Microsoft Login page? I am trying to implement the same module, and I can't figure out where to enter the credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was giving https instead of http as the redirect URI

so instead of

https://localhost:8080/microsoft/auth-callback/

use

http://localhost:8080/microsoft/auth-callback/

also in the postgresql database i was useing we should provide the value

> localhost:8080

into the table **django_site**