# AADSTS90102 error when using django-microsoft-auth for SSO with Azure AD

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I followed the steps in this tutorial to enable SSO with Azure Active Directory for the admin portion (to start) of my Django app:
https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Navigating to /admin yields this page, which is good:
[image]

Clicking Microsoft brings up this new window:
[image]

The important error seems to be:
AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute URI.

In this window, I used the browser console and found that a GET request was being made like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/50ce...90ac7/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=f4...27&redirect_uri=https,https://example.org/microsoft/auth-callback/&s...
```

Note the `redirect_uri=https,https://...`. It seems like that leading "https," is superfluous and is causing the problem. Any ideas where that could be coming from?

In my Azure app, the redirect URI is set to `https://example.org/microsoft/auth-callback/`:
[image]

I'm using Python 3.9.6, Django 3.2, django-microsoft-auth 2.4.0, NGINX 1.18.0, uvicorn 0.14.0

I've searched for help on this and haven't found anything relevant to my situation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the SO Thread Reference.

Use http as the redirect URI instead of https to resolve the issue in most cases.

use

http://localhost:8080/microsoft/auth-callback/

Instead of

https://localhost:8080/microsoft/auth-callback/

If there is a option,

Use localhost:8080 into the table django_site

Reference SO Thread: [django-microsoft-auth : The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288086/django-microsoft-auth-the-provided-value-for-the-input-parameter-redirect-uri)

Comment: I gave this a try, but, since this is for the production site (not a localhost dev environment), Azure does not allow using "http". The Azure UI says "Must start with HTTPS or http://localhost".

Answer (score 0):

As you think, the first `https` is superfluous, you just need to delete it.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/50ce...90ac7/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=f4...27&redirect_uri=https://example.org/microsoft/auth-callback/&s...`

By the way, I think there is no problem with the `redirect_uri` you set in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a problem of the redirecting URL. The example URL is coming from django site table. So first of all you need to enable the site:

```
#in settings.py
SITE_ID = 1
```

Afterwards you can go to the admin interface and set the url of the site to the correct domain. From my experience I know that it won't work without that.